# Kibana 7.5.1 : Hide management menu from user

Tags: kibana-7

I installed ELK 7.5.1 stack, and all works fine. My question is, how to hide management menu below from user? as i want the user to view the dashboard only after login.

What have done so far :-

- create new user
- create role and space privilages
- assign role to new user

Thanks

[user page : how to hide management menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUa3I.png)

[already setup space priviliges to view dashboard only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVtgN.png)